# Deny items to be removed from inventory slots.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to disallow players to remove a certain item from a certain inventory slot. What I have tried is to add a curse of binding to the item as following:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.hotbar.8 wool 1 0 {ench:[{id:10,lvl:1}]}
```

But as you may know, this only works for armor slots, not other inventory slots.

Comment: Can't you just spam that replaceitem command on a repeating command block?

Comment: @ppperry Then a player can remove it and use it for other purposes. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

**Killing items on the ground**

setup a scoreboard :

```
/scoreboard objective add Item dummy Item
```

Inside repeating active commandblocks (one that executes a command every thick) use these 3 commands:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.hotbar.8 wool 1 0 

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] Item 1 {Item:{id:wool,Count:1,Damage:8}}

/kill @e[type=Item,score_Item_min=1]﻿
```

The first command adds the item to a specific spot on the hotbar just like you're command but without the curse.

The second assigns any wool blocks with damage value 8 to the scoreboard and the third command kills all items assigned to the scoreboard.

**deleting items from unwanted inventory slots**

If you want to delete the item from another slot in the hotbar use this inside first command inside a active repeating commandblock.

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:8}]}
```

then add a comparator to that commandblock running into a normal command block executing:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.hotbar.1 air
```

This you will have to setup for each slot in the inventory. Note that the slot number in the testfor is 1 less than the slot in the replaceitem (and note the b after it)